# Error when building Apache 2.4.25 from source with open ssl 1.1.0c

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd, openssl

I have built Apache 2.4.25 with OpenSSL 1.0.2 successfully.

But Because of some security holes we found in our Internal tests,
I have been asked to patch Openssl with the latest version.
So I am **trying to build Apache httpd 2.4.25 with OpenSSL 1.1.0c (or) 1.1.0d**

My Environments

```
lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)
Release:        5.11
Codename:       Tikanga

Perl:           5.24
PCRE:           8.38
APR:            1.5.2
APR-util:       1.5.4
OpenSSL:        1.1.0c / 1.1.0d
```

All the above Apache dependencies have been successfully built and installed

Apache 2.4.25 - Installation steps

```
cd /my/softwares
tar -xvf httpd-2.4.25.tar -C /my/build/

cd /my/build/httpd-2.4.25/

./configure --prefix=/my/apache-httpd-2.4.25 \
    --with-pcre=/my/dependencies/pcre-8.38/ \
    --with-apr=/my/dependencies/apr-1.5.2 \
    --with-apr-util=/my/dependencies/apr-util-1.5.4 \
    --enable-ssl \
    --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c \
    --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps \
    --enable-mods-static=ssl

make // see below errors
make install
```

I am getting the below error when building Apache from source with open ssl.
Please help me in the right directions.

```
ssl_engine_init.c: In function 'make_dh_params':
ssl_engine_init.c:61: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
ssl_engine_init.c:62: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
ssl_engine_init.c:63: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
ssl_engine_init.c:63: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
ssl_engine_init.c: In function 'ssl_init_ctx_protocol':
ssl_engine_init.c:519: warning: 'TLSv1_client_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl/ssl.h:1598)
ssl_engine_init.c:520: warning: 'TLSv1_server_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl/ssl.h:1597)
ssl_engine_init.c:525: warning: 'TLSv1_1_client_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl/ssl.h:1604)
ssl_engine_init.c:526: warning: 'TLSv1_1_server_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl/ssl.h:1603)
ssl_engine_init.c:530: warning: 'TLSv1_2_client_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl/ssl.h:1610)
ssl_engine_init.c:531: warning: 'TLSv1_2_server_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl/ssl.h:1609)
ssl_engine_init.c: In function 'ssl_init_ctx_session_cache':
ssl_engine_init.c:641: warning: passing argument 2 of 'SSL_CTX_sess_set_get_cb' from incompatible pointer type
ssl_engine_init.c: In function 'use_certificate_chain':
ssl_engine_init.c:861: warning: implicit declaration of function 'BIO_s_file_internal'
ssl_engine_init.c:861: warning: passing argument 1 of 'BIO_new' makes pointer from integer without a cast
ssl_engine_init.c: In function 'ssl_init_server_certs':
ssl_engine_init.c:1201: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
make[3]: *** [ssl_engine_init.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/my/build/httpd-2.4.25/modules/ssl'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/my/build/httpd-2.4.25/modules/ssl'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/my/build/httpd-2.4.25/modules'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to build Apache with statically linked ssl libraries?
It is a fairly bad idea in my opinion. 
With dynamically linked libraries, you can just upgrade ssl when needed.
With static ones you will need to recompile apache every time ssl gets patched

Comment: I wasn't aware of them - Will remove them from my configure command.

Comment: --enable-ssl is fine, but you should be able to skip "--with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c \" safely

Comment: I used the below command to re-build again..                                  /configure --prefix=/my/apache-httpd-2.4.25 --with-pcre=/my/dependencies/pcre-8.38/ --with-apr=/my/dependencies/apr-1.5.2 --with-apr-util=/my/dependencies/apr-util-1.5.4 --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl-1.1.0c But still getting error as mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0):

From one of the online users comments

"*As of now, with the latest version Apache HTTPD 2.4.25, the 2.4 branch is not yet compatible with Openssl 1.1.x, So have to stick with the latest 1.0.2x and stay up to date on security issues.*"

"*There is no official statement, since OpenSSL 1.1.x became stable pratically "yesterday" there haven't been time and time to adapt 2.4 branch to it, all of this you can read about mainly in the dev and user httpd mailing list*"